# Do toilet bleach tablets prevent the spread of enteric diseases?

Tags: gastroenterology, hygiene, bleach, toilet-bowl

I am not a huge fan of adding bleach tablets to toilets, but my wife and I have experienced an unfortunate increase in stomach-related problems since we had children. Despite our attempts to regularly manually clean our toilets, I've begun to think about bleach tablets more often.

Flushing a toilet may spray a mist into the air. I have read that that mist can spread disease. Can adding bleach tablets to my toilets at home reduce the chance that that mist can effectively spread disease? If so are there specific health risks to using bleach tablets that offset this benefit?